# PHP's json_encode function adding "Array" before the object - why?

Tags: php, json, ajax

This is something that has just turned from annoying into downright infuriating.

I have a PHP script to register new users to a system and return a JSON response detailing either success or an error ("your password isn't long enough", "this username is already in use", that sort of thing), and no matter what I do, it is frankly determined to - rather than respond with just the PHP associative array as a JSON object i.e. starting with `{` - respond with `Array{your data here...`.

As you may expect, my jQuery doesn't like this one bit and rightly throws `unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data`.

```php
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');

/*
All the code that works with the DB and builds a response
*/

function_to_log_response_to_server(json_encode($response)); // This logs the response exactly as it should be (i.e. not preceded by "Array")
echo json_encode($response); // This line IMMEDIATELY follows the above
?>
```

How can I get PHP (or the json_encode function) to stop adding "Array" at the start of the response?

Comment: `json_encode` does not output anything. Look through your code.

Comment: If you comment out the call to "function_to_log_response_to_server()" does it work?  What if you put the json in a variable like $json = json_encode($response) before the function call, echo $json then call the function passing $json, and then echo $json again.  In other words, is json_encode() giving you what you want in the first place, if so then where is it getting changed?

Comment: Can you `var_dump($response)` ?